# Adobe air over TLS connection - throwing error

Tags: ssl, air

I'm trying to load an image file from an untrusted SSL location. I kept on hitting an alert when I try to do this. As per one of the solution online, I need to install the cert onto my machine which will avoid the errors [link](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/92215), I've done that, I've got rid of the errors that I previously got, now I'm seeing a new type of error which is pasted below. Is there a way to override this alert on a windows machine?

I've verified the link in the browser, they seem to work because we added the cert on our machines trusted root certificate authority.

The alert says

> Revocation information for the security certificate for this site is not available. Do you want to proceed?
>
> yes, no, view certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a CRL is missing in your server configuration?

Try something like this:

```
openssl ca -gencrl -out pathToYourCrl/ca.crl -crldays7
```

Of course you have to point to this path in your apache.conf as well.

Comment: Is there a way to overwrite this error from the adobe framework? all other browsers seems to ignore this error. Since adobe uses windows crl or ocsp validation this should not be a problem.